# SQL Aggregating over groups within colum

Tags: sql, r

I have inferred the following table

```
CustomerID | OrderType | Date
=============================
1          | A         | 1/1
1          | B         | 2/1
1          | A         | 3/1
2          | A         | 1/1
2          | A         | 4/1
....
```

from a table containing an additional ID-column, using grouping via CustomerID and OrderType.

In obtaining this tabular it astounded me, that I also need to select the Date column. Otherwise the each customerID-Ordertype pair only occurs once (e.g. without that column the 3rd line would be absent.)

In a next step I would like to count the number of Ordertype per Customer. 
I am able to do this in R (this can be easily done using dplyr). However, since the file is quite large (and memory is an issue in MS sql Management studio), I would prefer to obtain directly a table of the following form

```
Customer ID | Count(Type_A) | Count(Type_B)
===========================================
1           | 2             | 1
2           | 2             | 0 
....
```

As I said, this is an easy task with R. Can this also be obtained with SQL?
I believe an implementation might require some self joins but, so far, I was not able to solve this problem.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That are multiple aways to achieve it.

A simple example(you can use either count or sum this way):

```
select 
    CustomerID,
    COUNT(case when OrderType = 'A' then 1 end) [COUNT(Type_A)],
    COUNT(case when OrderType = 'B' then 1 end) [COUNT(Type_B)]
from myTable
group by
    CustomerID
```

Comment: should you also have to `group by` `ordertype`?

Comment: @vkp . . . Definitely  not.

Comment: No need to group by ordertype. that's the field you are applying your aggregation.

Comment: Thanks. Simple and yet beautiful

Comment: Note that  `COUNT(case...end):` could alternately be written as, e.g.  `SUM(OrderType = 'A')`

Answer (score 2):

For those interested in manipulating data frames using SQL inside R, they could use the function `sqldf` to pass the query that mxix wrote as a string:

```
df <- read.table(text ="CustomerID  OrderType  Date
                        1           A          1/1
                        1           B          2/1
                        1           A          3/1
                        2           A          1/1
                        2           A          4/1", 
                 header =TRUE)
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select 
    CustomerID,
    COUNT(case when OrderType = 'A' then 1 end) [COUNT(Type_A)],
    COUNT(case when OrderType = 'B' then 1 end) [COUNT(Type_B)]
from df
group by
    CustomerID")
```

Output:

```
  CustomerID COUNT(Type_A) COUNT(Type_B)
1          1             2             1
2          2             2             0
```